# @typescript-eslint/naming-convention ignore object inside a classname

Tags: regex, eslint

tl:dr, why is this REGEX incorrect : `classNames.*(.*{(?:.|\n)*?})` although it work in regex101 ?

I am using typescript with eslint. I setup some naming convention to variables type using [@typescript-eslint/naming-convention](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md). One of them is for object types, I would like the key of object to always be camelCase.

For this I simply use the rule

```
{
            "selector": "objectLiteralProperty",
            "format": ["camelCase"],
            "leadingUnderscore": "allow",
            "trailingUnderscore": "allow"
          },
```

With the above rule

this object is OK, because it is a plain object

```
  const test = {
    'myName': "Bob"
  };
```

this object is NOT OK

```
  const test = {
    'my-name': "Bob"
  };
```

Now, I am trying to make an exception for this rule. Since I am using react, sometimes I need to create dynamic class name, and I need to pass object that use a different convention  for the classnames : `'w-full py-1'`

I would like to allow this and ignore the `camelCase` only if the object is wrapped around a method `classNames`

this object is still NOT OK

```
  const test = {
    'my-name': "Bob"
  };
```

But this object is ok, because wrapped around `classNames({ })`

```
 className={classNames({
     'w-full py-1': true,
     'bg-blue-1/10': open,
 })}
```

I tried to setup my eslint config like this to allow any format for anything matching regex pattern like this : `classNames.*(.*{(?:.|\n)*?})`

```
          {
            "selector": "objectLiteralProperty",
            "format": ["camelCase"],
            "leadingUnderscore": "allow",
            "trailingUnderscore": "allow"
          },{
            "selector": "objectLiteralProperty",
            "format": null,
            "filter": {
              "regex": "classNames.*(.*{(?:.|\n)*?})",
              "match": true
            }
          },
```

But even thos this regex work on [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/J5TRuO/1) I get an error in eslint with

> Invalid regular expression: /classNames.*(.*{(?:.|
> )*?})/: Lone quantifier brackets

What is wrong with it ?

**EDIT**

I escaped the `{` and `}` like this : `classNames.*(.*\{(?:.|\n)*?\})` but when added to Eslint I get

> Invalid escape character in string.

so I moved to `classNames.*(.*\\{(?:.|\n)*?\\})` and now it still the same problem where it matches everything

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be that you didn't escape the parenthesis `()` that are part of the string and not the regex pattern

Try this: `classNames.*\(.*\{(?:.|\n)*?\}\)`
if eslint doesn't like the single `\` then

try this:`classNames.*\\(.*\\{(?:.|\n)*?\\}\\)`

**Edit**:More attempts

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WqN8Ph/1) `/(?<=\{classNames.*\(\{(?:.|\n)*').*(?=')/g`

or `/(?<=\{classNames.*\(\{(?:.|\\n)*').*(?=')/g`

This regex matches the object names that are surrounded by 'classNames'.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. The first pattern give me `Invalid escape character in string.jsonc(261)`

Comment: the second throw no error, but match also objects that are not included in a `classname({})`

Comment: I have updated my (pitiful) attempt at an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the `\n`. As you can see in the error message, it's been removed from the regex. I think if you escape it, it should work fine:

`"classNames.*(.*{(?:.|\\n)*?})"`

I hope that does it.